# Количество параметров в строке

Tags: java

Здравствуйте. Один рас пользователь может ввести 2-а слова, а другой рас 3-и, как определить сколько слов он ввел? Добавляться может только str2, то есть к примеру он один рас ввел:

> первое третье

А другой рас:

> первое второе третье

Вот к примеру мой код:

```
Scanner g = new Scanner(System.in);

String str1 = g.next();
String str2 = g.next();
String str3 = g.next();

if(str2.isEmpty()) {
//у нас только есть str1 и str3
} else {
//нам повезло, у нас есть три слова
}
```

Только у меня оно не работает.

Comment: Довольно естественно.

Как Вы представляете себе **пустое** слово?

Попробуйте написать такую последовательность символов.

Comment: @timedo Еще РА**З** выучите русский язык!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно принимать строку, а потом разбивать на слова

п.с. слова разделяются пробелами